# errno 98 address already in use, Bokeh server and UDP protocol

Tags: python, sockets, bokeh

So, I am trying to set up some dynamic plots on bokeh. I am actually getting the data every 10 hz via UDP. However, I am only able to deploy one server at once. Every time, I tried to open another server, the whole program crashes, and it said, "Errno 98 address already in use". The UDP protocol is only bound to one IP and one port, and only acting as receiver, does it have something to do with bokeh server every time I tried to open a new instance?

This is what I have for my UDP protocol:

```
UDP_IP_ADDRES=''    
UDP_port=5800;    
serverSock =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)    
serverSock.bind((UDP_IP_ADDRES,UDP_port)
```

I tried using :

```
serverSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serverSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
```

but none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to close/shutdown your socket. Simple use `servSocket.close()`, when you don't need it anymore.

Fastest solution is to reboot your system. Other way is to use check who is listening on your port using this:

```
lsof -i :your_port
```

and then kill that proces

```
kill pid
```